# Tableau Desktop on SAP ECC

Tags: tableau-api, sap-erp

Is it possible for Tableau Desktop to access the SAP ERP system? If so, what impact does that have on performance? I'm looking to provide real-time data at the source, but I'm not sure if the aforementioned is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Desktop can connect to the following SAP data types:

1. SAP HANA
2. SAP NetWeaver Business Warehouse
3. SAP Sybase ASE
4. SAP Sybase IQ

Tableau performance varies greatly by the performance of the underlying data source. If you have a slow server for instance, your Tableau experience will also be slow.